# Replot Loads and Boundary Conditions in Ansys APDL

Tags: ansys

I created an Ansys model and set boundary conditions (BCs) and loads.  Next I ran the solver to solve the model.  Now I would like to get a snapshot of the model showing boundary conditions and loads applied to model for a report.  When I try to replot I don't see any option for Loads and BCs.  How can I get model to replot with boundary conditions and loads.

Answer (score 1):

To replot with boundary conditions and loads:

```
/PBC,ALL, ,1
/REP
```

To replot without boundary conditions and loads:

```
/PBC,ALL, ,0
/REP
```

Reference: https://www.sharcnet.ca/Software/Ansys/16.2.3/en-us/help/ans_cmd/Hlp_C_PBC.html